Is this use of ておいて related to "leaving it as it is"? What is the exact nuance here?

「それで、なぜ笑顔だったんです？」
と、再び食事を始める。己との態度の差は聞いておいて本題ではないらしい。

The main character gets asked why he was smiling at the phone and his narration thinks that. In the previous sentence the main character expressed his desire to talk with his friend about their relationship. Instead the friend changed the subject just asked him why he was smiling at the phone.
The internal narration denotes then that the main character understands that the friend wished to drop the subject.
What nuance does ておいて give here?  "Save for later and leave it as is?

The phrase ておいて here carries the nuance that the action feels unnecessary or implies some criticism.

聞いたけれど本題ではなかったらしい。
聞いておいて本題ではなかったらしい。

Both mean "(He) asked (something), but that was not the main topic." The first simply states the fact, while the second conveys the narrator's annoyance at the friend's action, suggesting that it was unnecessary or that the friend is avoiding the main issue.
